# Cut string after certain number of chracters in Unix Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a string/file which contains some data that needs to be mailed using an API. But it doesn't allow message length to be greater than N.

So now I want to trim the contents of the file to N characters.

Suppose the contents of the file are as shown below:

```
2020-09-28 03:13:41,288 ERROR [.] [main]: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException 
2020-09-28 03:13:41,298 ERROR [.] [main]: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myPackage.anotherPackage.DoSomething.processSomeData(MagicallyPullData.java:98)
at com.myPackage.anotherPackage.DoSomething.processSomeData(MagicallyPullData.java:56) 
at com.myPackage.anotherPackage.DoSomething.processSomeData(MagicallyPullData.java:112)
```

I want to get 50 characters for todays date say

```
[main]: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So today's date pattern should be matched, but date shouldn't be included, whole string should be shrunk to 50 characters after that.

I wrote the following

```
cat /home/myproject/logs/errors.log | grep "`date --date='today' '+%Y-%m-%d'`"
```

But this gives all the lines that have today's date.

This script is going to be a cron job that runs everyday.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There is more implied than just "50 characters for today's date". Do you want only the first line, the first line that matches, the first 50 characters beyond the date that match on every line? Please be more specific. You can use `sed s/<regex>//` to remove the leading date from lines that match, and `head -c 50` to get only the first 50 characters.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. For the first line that matches today's date, 50 characters starting after the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `grep` + `cut`, consider Awk.

```sh
awk -v ddmmyy="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" '$1 == ddmmyy {
    print substr($0, 1, 50) }' /home/myproject/logs/errors.log
```

If you only want the first 50 characters from the first occurrence on today's date, simply add `; exit` after the closing parenthesis, before the closing brace.

If you want only the text from character position 35 forward, change the second argument to `substr` from `1` to `35`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the date using `cut -d' ' -f2-`, then pipe it through `head -c50` to get the first 50 bytes:

```
grep "`date --date='today' '+%Y-%m-%d'`" /home/myproject/logs/errors.log | cut -d' ' -f2- | head -c50
```

Comment: This also does my job but the one that I marked as the answer suited better for my requirement. 
Thank You for taking the time and answering my query.